# Passing an ID to Quasar and use of guards with children components on default setup

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm trying to work with the default setup in Quasar and having a hard time with the most basic operation.

I have a list of tasks at the route /tasks which links to individual items at task/taskId (ie, task/5).

I had this setup using vue and vue-router previously and was setting the ID and loading the appropriate record with the beforeRouteUpdate guard and it was great. Then I switched to Quasar, setup with the basic cli. The task route is now a child of the main layout component which means beforeRouteUpdate is not called from within the child. I've tried using beforeEnter as a per-route guard, which, in the documentation says it has access to 'this', but it results to undefined.

I must be missing something because routing to /tasks and task/5 should be fundamental and I would think there's a best practice for achieving this within the default Quasar install.

My routes:

```
{
  path: '/tasks',
  name: 'tasks',
  component: () => import('layouts/MyLayout.vue'),
  children: [
    { path: '', component: () => import('pages/tasks/Index.vue') }
  ]
},
{
  path: '/task/:taskId',
  name: 'task',
  component: () => import('layouts/MyLayout.vue'),
  children: [
    { path: '', component: () => import('pages/tasks/Show.vue') }
  ],
  props: true
},
```

I'm not sure what other code to include, no sense in posting the beforeRouteUpdate from my child component since it's not called. I can't put in the parent component MyLayout.vue because that runs for all pages, not just tasks. Is there a best practice for refreshing the data using the prop from the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I can see you are loading the same component for `/tasks` and for `/task/:taskId`.

So this is not a Quasar problem but a Vue Router one. Vue Router in order to be optimal when sees the same component for the same route is not destroying and recreating the component.

As solution, in the `<router-view></router-view>` component you can add a `key` so when you switch route the component will re-render:

```
<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
```

Another solution would be to add a watcher to the `MyLayout.vue` component, so whenever the route changes, that watcher will be executed but the component will not be destroyed and re-created.

```
watch: {
 // will fire on route changes
'$route': {
  handler(newRoute) {
    if (newRoute.params.taskId) { // if it has `taskId` prop
      // you are in the `/task/:taskId` route
      // add your code here
    }
  },
  immediate: true,
  deep: true
}
```

Comment: Same component but different instance with different children. I figured it out just after I posted the question. It had to do with trying to manipulate the taskId. I had to create a local variable to work with. I wasn't getting an error like I had on a basic vue-router SPA.

Comment: Actually - I thought I had it then revisited your answer when the problem persistested and adding :key did the trick. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a local variable for the id and work with that for loading the data. Once I did that, everything worked. I realized I was having the same issue on a standard (non-Quasar) app    import { mapState } from 'vuex'

```
export default {
  props: ['taskId'],
  data () {
    return {
      id: this.taskId
    }
  },

  this.$store.dispatch('tasks/fetchTask', this.id)
```

If I do it this way it seems to work without beforeRouteUpdate, even if I navigate directly from task/5 to task/6